# How android application work with 3G/GPRS/EDGE

Tags: android, openfire, 3g, gprs, cellular-network

I developed an android app to receive a location and then send a message to collect at a MySQL server via XMPP protocol.

I want to know a differences between using WiFi and 3G/GPRS/EDGE.

If I use WiFi, it can connect to server directly, right? But if I use 3G/GPRS/EDGE, is it possible to send msg to server?
If possible, am I set up or need to do something to check the differences mobile connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting up an HTTP service that would pass parameters to the database and pass the records (if any) back. This way it will work over public networks for sure.